# Feathersjs - Property 'feathers' does not exist on type 'Socket'

Tags: typescript, socket.io, typescript-typings, feathersjs

I'm trying to add a property to a socket connection so that I can identify the user and send a reply only to him.
I found solution here: [How to add parameters to a FeathersJS socket connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54421486/how-to-add-parameters-to-a-feathersjs-socket-connection)

Unfortunately, this solution doesn't work in typescript.
I got this message: Property 'feathers' does not exist on type 'Socket'.

```
app.configure(
socketio(function (io) {
io.use(function (socket, next) {
  socket.feathers.token = socket.handshake.query.token; // Here is problem
  next();
});
```

})
);

I am looking for a good solution to this problem. Should I try to extend the type or better not?
Is there any other way to add something to a connection so that I can access this property in a channels.ts?

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to extend the Socket type and use it.

Considering that you extend the object, it make sense to extend the type as well.

Look at the following [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIA9gGcygOYDKA9ggNYRgAqAngA4oDeAUMsgBZwgAmWH5AXMk7UA3C2RYiAWwpt8g4WIC+TJmDooMkbhC7EyFGvWQBeNJhz595KhuQAyZM1YwIcMG2hZBz1sjBE5CAKIKLiSsqqMACuIAi4RCDIMEREABSSBmCCWhA6eiQ2RhAANMggEOjZQqEAlE7imTYAdK7unlBYzQFBphKFFM0c3Lxw5M0AjtHQ1N2BecpAA)

```
interface ExistingSocketType {
  handshake: any;
  something: any;
}

type ExtendedSocketType = ExistingSocketType & {
  feathers: {
    token: any;
  };
}

function foo(socket: ExtendedSocketType, next: any) {
  socket.feathers.token = socket.handshake.query.token;
}
```

Replace the `ExistingSocketType` by the Socket type of the package that you use.